# How to Pass Variable?

Tags: vbscript

I create code like following. I want to pass the variable `rand` and  `randd` in the

```
iret = iim2.iimPlay("rand")
iret = iim1.iimPlay("randd")
```

How to do this?

```
Set iim1= CreateObject ("imacros")
Set iim2= CreateObject ("imacros")

Dim max,min,rand,randd,maxx,minn
max=2
min=15
Randomize
rand = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
WScript.Echo rand

maxx=2
minn=15
Randomize
randd = Int((maxx-minn+1)*Rnd+minn)
WScript.Echo randd

For m = 1 to 1
  iim1.iimInit("-fx -fxProfile t2")
  iim2.iimInit("-cr")

  iret = iim2.iimPlay("rand")
  iret = iim1.iimPlay("randd")

  iret = iim2.iimExit()
  iret = iim1.iimExit()
Next
```

Comment: VB.NET & VBScript and completely different things (deleted the VB.NET tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes:

```
iret = iim2.iimPlay(rand)
iret = iim1.iimPlay(randd)
```

VBScript does not expand variables in quotes, so `"rand"` is passed as the literal string "rand" instead of the value of the variable `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: remove the quotes like this:

iret = iim2.iimPlay(rand)

iret = iim1.iimPlay(randd)

You are passing strings called "rand" and "randd". Variables aren't encased in quotes. 
In addition, you are constructing the same object (iret) twice, I'm not sure why.
You may have other issues as well, but this is a good start.